# Data level Authorization filter in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authorization

We have Role based Authorization implemented in our mvc application

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ProjectEngineer")]
```

Our need is now to extend this to data level in such way that Project Engineer from department X can only view data from his department and so on.
Need a mapping between security group and what departments it can view data from.
I am looking for the best way to implement this.

Comment: Cant you just return the records for the user based on their department in the method?

Comment: But there are many pages queries need to change.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a reason to not design your app correctly?

Comment: Yes , but as you suggested we retrieve the records based on users department.